# Configure target system

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Trying to configure hello world visual c++ Cmake project. I would like to build binary on Linux system. I'm interested in both WSL and and linux machine connected via ssh.

I have defined SSH connection in `Connection Manager`:
[image]

But still don't see this connection in `Target system` selection menu:
[image]

How to get visible remote machines in `Target system`?

I have several WSL machines on my system. How to configure VS in order to use them as target machines?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 preview.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-170#connect-to-wsl

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/deploy-run-and-debug-your-linux-project?view=msvc-170#separate_build_debug